# How can I do 64-bit arithmetic in Perl?

Tags: perl, 64-bit, signed

I am a perl newbie,

Can I simply use 64-bit arithmetic in Perl?

For example

```
$operand1 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;   # 48 bit value
$operand2 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;   # 48 bit value

$Result = $operand1 * $operand2;
```

- I am basically looking for a
  replacement for the int64_t in perl.
- Is there any way to mention, if the
  variable is signed or unsigned?

Comment: Do you really want 64-bit arithmetic or big numbers? Do you want it to overflow after 64 bits?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, however you need to have Perl compiled with 64-bit support.

Comment: "use bigint" will ensure that it always works.  (If you want absolute speed, you picked the wrong programming language.)

Comment: Perl is often used in bioinformatics and other fields requiring high-performance. If your numbers are sure to fit within 64 bits, then this answer will create better performing code. Just make sure to use a recent version of Perl, and you may want to compile it yourself.

"64-bit support is now considered to be mature"
http://dev.perl.org/perl5/news/2002/07/18/580ann/

Comment: Even with 64 bit support, you'd need a `use integer;` to avoid getting a (rounded) floating point result and instead get a (high-bits truncated) integer result.

Answer (score 11):

See [bigint](http://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html):

> Transparent BigInteger support for Perl...
>
> All operators (including basic math operations) except the range operator `..` are overloaded. Integer constants are created as proper BigInts.
>
> Floating point constants are truncated to integer. All parts and results of expressions are also truncated.
>
> Unlike [integer](http://perldoc.perl.org/integer.html), this pragma creates integer constants that are only limited in their size by the available memory and CPU time...

Comment: +1 thank you, but I could not use functions like hex() etc ~~~

Comment: Alphaneo, actually you can do  `$a = Math::BigInt->new("0x".$your_int)` and `$a->as_hex()`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Perl automatically handles large integer arithmetic for you. However, Perl does not offer a distinction between signed and unsigned types (there's no need, since there are not fixed bounds on large integer range).

The [perlnumber](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html) manual page has more information about the different numeric formats supported by Perl.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "distinction between signed and unsigned values"?

Comment: Right, I should have said "types" instead of "values". Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, 64bit arithmetic in Perl is one, but what it is displayed by sprintf %d  %u  and %s, is second.
Current perl version supports 64bits without problems, but sprintf %d format not, %b likewise .

Answer (score 0):

`use bigint` will make Perl handle arbitrary size integers correctly without integer overflow.

Eg.:

```
use bigint;
print 1 << 256;
```

will print:

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```